# Hyperlink image makes red box in background

Tags: html, image, css, hyperlink, hover

When I hover over my image in my banner it makes a red box appear behind the image, I tried to fix it by making the first a link a class of "logo" and making specific link info for it, but that doesn't seem to be working. I think it's because the link itself is logo and therefore not picking up the link. What is the most effective way to resolve this issue?

HTML5

```
<header class="main-header">
        <a class="logo" href="../index.html">
        <img src="../Images/logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>   
<nav><ul>
    <li><a href="../index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="../news/news.html">NEWS</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="location.html">LOCATION</a></li>
</ul></nav>
```

CSS3

```
/* Define Hyperlink Info */

a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #C71F0E;
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    text-decoration: none;
}


/* Defines the header banner */
.main-header {
    background-image: url('../Images/flag-header.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1510px 180px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 70%; 
}

.main-header img{
    background: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 140px;
    margin-left: 3%;
}

/* Defines Image Link */

.logo {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.logo a {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.logo a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.logo a:link, a:visted {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css selector `.logo a:hover` looks for an `a` tag that has the state `:hover` which is *inside* a `div` with the `.logo` class. This isn't what you're trying to accomplish, as your `a` tag has the class `.logo` itself.

This is the css that you need:

```
a.logo:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

This looks for an `a` tag that has the class `.logo` and has the `:hover` state. This will select the `a` surrounding your logo image and you shouldn't get a red box on hover anymore.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was trying to do, ug, it's just one of those days -_-. Thank you